# Identifying an '80s TV episode or movie with a boy whose consciousness was programmed into a computer

Tags: story-identification, tv, artificial-intelligence, computers

I remember watching a TV show in the eighties - either a standalone movie or an episode of a series, I can't be sure which. The plot was about a young boy (teenager or late preteen) who was a genius with computers. He manages to make his computer do amazing things.

Sadly, his young life is cut short by illness. But he leaves a curious legacy for his computer-naive sister to find: a *very* long program (apparenly in BASIC, from what I recall - I used to program in this language, and I think I identified some of the commands and syntax as being BASIC) with instructions to key it into the system.

She diligently sets about typing the entire program into the system - very slowly ("hunt and peck") at first, then getting really efficient with the entry as she becomes more familiar with the QWERTY keyboard. Her ramp up in speed is meant to show the passage of time (because it's a *really* long program!).

When she finally executes the code, she is astonished to find that, somehow, her late brother's consciousness has been resurrected in the PC. If memory serves, the PC even talks to her in a typical (retro) computer-synthesised monotone.

I guess this vastly predated movies like Transcendence, with a broadly similar theme. It would be great if someone can help me identify this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is Tales from the Darkside http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0716962/reviews 
'Mookie and Pookie' stars Justine Bateman of 'Family Ties' as Susan a.k.a. Pookie, the female in a set of fraternal twins who's very much devoted to her brother Kevin a.k.a. Mookie (Ron Asher). Unfortunately, Mookie is terminally ill and passes away shortly into the episode. But his knowledge of technology allows him to continue being in touch with Pookie and their parents. The mother (Tippi Hedren) is willing to be open minded on the subject, but the father (George Sims) believes this is just an unhealthy fantasy on Pookies' part

Comment: Oh my god, you're spot on! Thank you so much! I managed to find a full video of this online and it's exactly as I remember: http://www.theparanormalsociety.org/entertainment/shows/172-tales-from-the-darkside/season-1/1477-tales-from-the-darkside-s01e05-mookie-and-pookie I think the episode stuck in my head because the girl is *really* cute and I guess I developed a ten year old crush on her. :)